# Narrow fonts for Chinese characters?

Tags: characters, fonts

Is there a half-width font for Chinese characters? I have a half-width font for Japanese and it covers a lot of Chinese characters but not all. By "half-width", I mean you can display Chinese characters like English alphabet as shown in this [pic](http://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/img/wf/docs/389/287/image1_s.jpg). I quickly looked it up in English but no result. I feel there must be some somewhere, since there are [narrow fonts for English](http://merviemilia.com/sites/default/files/images/hotfont7_sixcaps.png) and Japanese at least, as far as I know?

Comment: it seems that all fonts for Chinese glyph are fixed-width fonts, so that no narrow fonts. Chinese glyph is a square box (not like Latin-like characters), so that need fixed width font supports.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the option to choose "half-width" or 半角, as opposed to "full-width" 全角, is used in Chinese input systems only for punctuation and other symbols, but not for Chinese characters.

You can read more about it here:

http://blog.csdn.net/kevinhg/article/details/8702462

From what I can discern, the original reason for having "narrow-width" and "full-width" characters was to make sure that CJK and English text could be properly aligned.

Answer (score 2):

is that the effect you want to achieve？
[image: narrow down the characters]
actually，I have searched some Chinese narrow fonts，but it seems not the effect.
So my advice is using Fonts function of Word/Excel,etc.

Comment: Good idea, though my advice is not using it at all. It's just super ugly and unreadable..

Comment: yes. After doing some search, I  haven't found the narrow fonts from Microsoft fonts collection. There does exist some narrow fonts designed by individuals for commercial uses. Maybe you could search it by yourself using Chinese search engine [link](http://baidu.com) ,the Chinese keywords : 窄字体 or 细高字体 or 细长字体. Wish you have a better luck :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there ARE narrow Chinese fonts. Check out the whole family of 「方正兰亭黑 Pro」 or 「汉仪旗黑」.

See one of the narrow fonts of the 旗黑 family: [汉仪旗黑X3](http://hanyi.com.cn/productdetail.phphttp://hanyi.com.cn/productdetail.php?id=671)

But this is a rather expensive approach, and probably not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese characters has halfwidth and fullwidth forms . But I guess that's not what you ask for: The normal Chinese characters you saw are all half-width.

The 1st line are normal characters we see/use daily. It's half-width.

The 2nd line are full-width characters.

[image: pic]